# Using jQuery Mobile data-role="popup" from within a page that is heavily scripted and styled

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

Ok, I basically have a page that is already mobile-friendly, but it doesn't use any jQuery mobile whatsoever to accomplish this.  There is a CSS Stylesheet specifically for mobile devices that handles how the page looks in mobile browsers quite nicely.  However, wanting to add some jquery mobile functionality to the page without it affecting any of the other elements.  Mainly, I want to add a `data-role="popup"` effect, only for mobile devices to add in the ability to select additional menu items (will be sub-menu items actually).  In any case would like to add in this ability directly into the current non-jquerymobile page, within a `<div>` tag specifically, in order to keep it sized properly.  All I want is a button that says `Sections` and when clicked performs a similar effect as the jquerymobile `data-role="popup"` effect.

Can this be done with jquery mobile?  Or do I have to perform the slide effect in jQuery without the use of jquery-mobile?

So, for example:

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="header">
        <div id="header_image">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <nav id="main_menu" class="nav center">
        <div class="floatright star_menu_right">&#9733;</div><div class="floatleft star_menu_left">&#9733;</div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a accesskey="1" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a accesskey="2" href="highlights.html">Highlights</a></li>
            <li><a accesskey="3" href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>
            <li><a accesskey="4" href="tracks.html">Tracks</a></li>
            <li><a accesskey="5" href="sponsors.html">Sponsors / Exhibits</a></li>
            <li><a accesskey="6" href="travel.html">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a accesskey="7" href="register.html">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="body">
        <!-- I would like to place the button to open up the jquery mobile popup in here -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

So, I'm thinking that this can only be done via an iframe element, but would be nice if it could be added inside of the div with a position: relative and it would not take up the whole page, yet, I need the popup to take up the entire page when it slides out.  Any ideas?

Comment: You use a custom build of JQM including this widget http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: But all I want is the popup functionality and the slide that comes with it.  Touching the button should provide the popup to slide in from the left.  Which options do I need?  Do I need the core?

Comment: Just 1 problem: Custom Builds via that url do not work at all.  Panel doesn't work and I've linked both CSS files and the .js file in the head.  It doesn't work!

Comment: Actually, just realized, what I want is the Panel option, not the popup.  And I have tried it with the panel features, and it does not work, gives me undefined variable `define`

Comment: The custom build doesn't work?

Comment: There has already been reported issues with panels in the stable releases.  So I download the latest release custom-build and it does the same thing that jQuery Mobile does, which is mess everything up.  I guess this is impossible!  Argg!